# Integrating $\int\limits_{-3}^3(x^2-3)^3dx$ just using these two properties?

Tags: calculus, integration

So far with my textbook of Calculus I (Apostol) I've learned to integrate polynomials and I would like to know whether it's possible to integrate this one just using the following two properties:

To integrate: $$\int_{-3}^3(x^2-3)^3dx$$

Properties:

**(a)** Invariance Under Translation:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)dx$$

**(b)** Expansion and Contraction of the Interval of Integration:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \frac{1}{k}\int_{ka}^{kb} f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$$

For instance, the previous exercise was

$$\int_0^3(2x-5)^3dx$$

I know that it can be expanded and then each term can be integrated by applying linearity. There is also a technique of substitution that can be used, although I don't know how it works.

Well for the other exercise I did this:

$$\begin{align*}&\int_0^3\left[2\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)\right]^3dx\qquad \Leftarrow \text{Factor out the }2.\\
&=\int_0^38\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^3dx\\
&=8\int_0^3\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^3dx\\
&=8\int\limits_{-5/2}^{1/2}x^3 \qquad \Leftarrow \text{Apply property (a).}\\
&=[2x^4]\Bigg|_{-5/2}^{1/2} = -78\end{align*}$$

I've verified the result and it's okey.

Can something like this be done with the integral above?

This was my attempt:

$$\begin{align*}&\int_{-3}^3(x^2-3)^3dx\\
&= \int_{-6}^0(x^2)^3dx\\
&= \int_{-6}^0x^6dx\\
&=\frac{x^7}{7}\Bigg|_{-6}^0\end{align*}$$

which is not correct.

Comment: Those "properties" are just fancy dress-ups of integration by substitution, by the way.

Comment: @GFauxPas If so, is there a way to apply these two ''properties'' then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't shift $x^2$ the way you shift $x$.  Note that the value of the integrand at the lower limit before your shift is $6$, but after the shift it is $36$.  Using your rules, you could do $$\int_{-3}^3(x^2-3)^3dx=\int_{-6}^0((x+3)^2-3)^3dx$$but while correct it is not useful.